# How to visualize newtonian objects in term of harmonic oscillators?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-electrodynamics, visualization

From the group $U(1)$ in QED, via group representation we get the harmonic oscillators. However, I still have a hard time to imagine newtonian objects (computer, headphone, etc) as a combination of oscillators. I have take a look at [classical limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_limit) but the visualization is still vague.

Let's say I have a glass breaking. How to visualize it in oscillations?

[image]

Comment: It is a really, really long trip. The rugged path is dubbed "classical limit".

Comment: @CosmasZachos can you elaborate?

Comment: You may, painfully, discuss the classical limit, in phase space, of one oscillator; repackage trillions of these to classical field theory, reversing second quantization. Now, you claim you have an adequate classical field theoretic description of your phenomenon. Shortcut to models. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the object comprises $n$ degrees of freedom, and we work in a Cartesian coordinate system for these degrees of freedom, so each coordinate $q_i$ is $0$ at a stable equilibrium. The kinetic energy is of the form $\sum_i\frac12m_i\dot{q}_i^2$; the potential energy is of the form $\sum_i\frac12k_iq_i^2$, plus higher-order terms if an exact description of the system is anharmonic. (Cross terms, e.g. a term proportional to $q_1q_2$, can be deleted by rotating the coordinate axes.) Close enough to the equilibrium, such terms can be neglected. Such a harmonic approximation is of $n$ uncoupled harmonic oscillators.